# How can I load text into my screen on screen change in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am working on an application where one of my screens has some labels and text input fields. Whenever the user navigates to this screen, I'd like for some kind of `load()` function to check for data in a JSON file. If it finds data, it can load this data into the screen in the respective text input fields. If not, then no worries.

I am able to store and retrieve data form a JSON file easily enough, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to store this information into the screen in question whenever I navigate there! Is there some way to have a function run every time the screen appears that will fill in these text input fields?

***texttest.kv***

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
        id: main_screen
    SetupWindow:
        id: setup_screen

<SetupWindow>
    name: "setup"
    hostpy: hostkv
    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "Host or IP: "

            TextInput:
                id: hostkv
                multiline: False
```

***texttestapp.py***

```
...
...
...
class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class SetupWindow(Screen):
    hostpy = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(SetupWindow,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hostpypy.Text = "This is a test"

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

...
...
...
```

As you can see, I tried with `__init__(self,**kwargs)`, but this seems to be the wrong solution. What can I do to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer: Kivy actually has it's own API for this, which I had overlooked. Specifically, you can use on_pre_enter() or on_enter() to get this to work. The documentation for it is located here: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen